# Get the whole array by range indexing

Tags: python, arrays, range

To retrieve a sub range of elements of an array, we can write `myData[from : to]` syntax.

I have a function, the simplified variant looks like this:

```
def myFunction(fromIndex, toIndex):
    return myData[fromIndex: toIndex]
```

Let's assume I can't / don't want to change the behavior of `myFunction`, but in some cases I want to get the whole array (ie. in theory `fromIndex = 0, toIndex = len(myData)`. I can write `x = myFunction(0, len(myData))`, but in this case I have to know what ˙myData˙ means.

Is there any other way? Something like `x = myFunction(, )`, which would expand to `return myData[ : ]` and return the (copy of the) whole array. Does this range-indexing syntax has some special symbols? `myData[0 : 0 or None] == myData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `None` values for either/both of the argument defaults. Natively, `some_list[None:None]` returns the whole list.

```
def myFunction(fromIndex=None, toIndex=None):
    return myData[fromIndex: toIndex]

# myFunction() will return the whole list
```

Comment: Ah, the only one variant I didn't try... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One more but similar

```
myData = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]

def myFunction(fromIndex=None, toIndex=None):
    return myData[fromIndex: toIndex]

print(myFunction(fromIndex=0))
```